# Redirect with grunt-contrib-proxy

Tags: javascript, proxy, coffeescript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-connect

I might be doing something wrong but I am unable to force grunt-contrib-proxy to do a simple redirect.

In my gruntfile.coffeee (yup coffeescript) I have the following server configuration:

```
 connect:
        devserver:
            options:
                port: 9001
                base: "./"
            proxies: [{
                context: "/",
                host: 'dev.staging.com'
                changeOrigin: true
            }]
```

I also added:
grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-connect-proxy"
 and updated my task with "configureProxies:devserver"

I believe that this should redirect any call to dev.staging.com,
so when I type in http://localhost:9001 i should be redirected to url http://dev.staging.com

However it doesn't seem like proxy is workign at all. I have tried multiple configurations (even with rewrite) but still no luck.

I might be doing something wrong but i can't figure what...

Grunt compiles and runs the task properly.

Comment: Now when i change context: "/api" I get:
"Cannot GET /" whenever I start my app. I think I will swotch to some other proxy. Isn't there any other simple tool that will just do a redirect without all this unneccessary configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that documentation is missing the important fact thay you MUST add middleware to your server options:

proxySnippet = require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest

middleware: (connect, options) =>
    return [proxySnippet]